# Why can't I query other users' 2FA registration details?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to check which users on Azure have 2FA turned on on their accounts.

I have found a few examples online which claim to achieve this, but it only seems to work when querying myself - I can't check other users.

So if I run

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$user = "bassie@domain.com"
$pass= convertto-securestring "Password123" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$pass
$O365Cred = Get-Credential $mycred
Connect-MsolService -Credential $O365Cred

$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName bassie@domain.com
$user.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
```

I can see that `StrongAuthenticationUserDetails` contains

```
ExtensionData          : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AlternativePhoneNumber : 
Email                  : 
OldPin                 : 
PhoneNumber            : +27 1111111111
Pin                    :
```

Which makes sense, as my account has 2FA activated with the text message method selected, so I expect to see that phone number there. All other Strongauthentication-`properties are blank.

However, if I try getting the same for any other user, `StrongAuthenticationUserDetails` is always blank.

Why is this? I assume its to do with permissions, but if so , **which permissions?** And where can I find this information?

All I need to do is check who has 2FA switched off, so that we can bug those users and get them to register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you should have `Global administrator` role, then you can read that information.

You can via Azure portal to check the permission: `Azure Active Directory` -> `Users` -> `Directory Role` :

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks Jason.Do you know of any resources where I can check what type of activities require global admin rights, or a list of features granted after becoming a global admin?

Comment: @Bassie About Azure active directory role, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles-azure-portal).